# Upsert In MySql without ON DUPLICATE KEY (single query without procedure)

Tags: mysql

I have two table A, B. Where A is master table B is stage table. Many stage table get created B(for different state[AP, MH, UP, TN..] by updates provided by these states) exist and need to upsert in table A Monthly.

```
A- Id(Primery Key), Name, Email, ContactNumber, State, TimeStamp, Active(True, False)
```

A contains all data from each states, with last update date as time stamp and With flags.

```
B- Name, Email, ContactNumber
```

For now B is is considered to be updates from state AP. And contains updates means, B can have some row deleted which was earlier and some added and can have few same Previous rows.

I have to upsert by joning(on name, email, contact_number) all the updates for AP in such way,

- IF row only present in A then `Active_flag is False`
- IF row present in both then UPDATE row in A as `timestamp=now() and active_flag=True`
- If row present in B insert into A with extra values `STATE=AP and timestamp=now() and active=True`

Is it possible using `CASE, or IF-ELSE` (Will it be fast instead of using multiple query like first update and insert)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for a `REPLACE INTO` command, as described in [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) with mysql's  select syntax (`insert into sometable select * from anothertable`), like this:

```
replace into mastertable m
select
  field1, field2, field3, now()
from
  stagetable s
outer join
  mastertable m2 on m2.id=s.id
where
  m2.ActiveFlag=true or m2.ActiveFlag is null
```

Of course I didnt try this, but this would be the general idea.

Comment: Forgot to mention: this way usually runs a lot faster than multiple queries. And by a lot I mean seconds compared to minutes.